# PHP regular expression

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Собрал регулярное выражение `[\\\]+[nfvabrt0]{1}` для замены некоторых символов (`\n`, `\t`, `\0` и т.д.) функцией preg_replace() [тут](https://regex101.com/r/Brf1Cq/1). Вроде работает, но скрипт при вводе `"С:\Program Files"` возвращает `"С:Pogm Files"` при вводе `"127.0.0.1"` возвращает `"127...1"`.
Пробовал разные флаги результат тот же.
Подскажите ошибку.

Comment: Если вы более подробно опишите задачу, может дадим Вам более ясный и подробный ответ. А для простых замен возможно можно и использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: В регулярке два обратных слеша, stackoverflow удаляет второй.

Comment: Задача фильтровать пользовательский ввод. запретить использовать символы вроде \0 или \n

Comment: @Junior, а что должен возвращать на указанный ввод?

Comment: str_replace() не подходит по причине  обратный слэш обратный слэш nn возвратят \n

Comment: заменять символы \n \t \0 идт на ''. другими словами просто удалять. ну и ввод вроде \ \ \ n n (без пробелов) также удалять.

Answer (score 2):

Каждый из управляющих символов (`\n`, `\t`, ...) - это **один целый символ** (не два). Ведущий слэш - способ записи такого символа, а вовсе не отдельный, самостоятельный символ. Как следствие, отрывать слэш от "буковки" в регулярном выражении нельзя.

Правильное выражение должно иметь вид:

```
$output = preg_replace("/[\n\f\v\a\b\r\t\0]+/", '', $input);
```

Чтобы не писать всю эту кучу символов ручками, в PCRE есть символьный класс `[:cntrl:]`. Вот как его можно использовать для решения той же самой задачи:

```
$output = preg_replace("/[[:cntrl:]]+/", '', $input);
```

О других символьных классах вы можете узнать из [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

A вот и рабочий пример кода: https://3v4l.org/cjiLI

Comment: Ваш пример работает прекрасно. но если данные поступают из формы они остаются неизменными. Как это исправить?

Comment: Значит из формы вы получаете не отдельные управляющие символы, а два символа: слэш + буква. А для замены таких пар вполне подойдет регулярное выражение `/\\[nfvabrt0]/`. Но это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: я имею введу это: https://3v4l.org/9bHoT , извините за назойливость.)

Comment: Еще раз: если вы передаете через форму **управляющие символы**, то используйте выражение из ответа. Если вы передаете **пару символов** (слэш + буква), используйте выражение `/\\[nfvabrt0]/`.

Comment: Извините еще раз но этот пример возвращает тоже самое: https://3v4l.org/cDgS2

Comment: Вы ведь знаете, в чем разница одинрных и двойных кавычек в PHP? Напомню, они по разному работают с управляющими последовательностями ;)

Comment: Да я знаю, проблема в том что что данные нужно отчистить из формы, а она как я понимаю передает результат в одинарных кавычках. Извините что достаю просто пытаюсь найти решение :)

Comment: Форма вообще ничего не знает ни о кавычках, ни о PHP. Если вы То, что вы передаете через форму последовательность двух символов `\ ` и `n` это вовсе не означает, что на сервер придет один символ перевода строки `\n`. А вот вам и крошечный пример на подумать: https://3v4l.org/jH68V

Comment: А теперь повторю самое важное еще раз: если вы передаете через форму **управляющие символы**, регулярное выражение из ответа их уберет.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. :)